# Copyright of the world described in the novells "A Song of Ice and Fire"

Tags: copyright

I want to create from scratch a map that resembles the world described in the novells "A Song of Ice and Fire". My map will have a similar coastline and will use some of the names of the places from the books.

Am I legally allowed to do that? Are there some restrictions to what I can do with this map (e.g. share it for non-profit purposes)?

EDIT

I have seen the map a while ago in a web site and I am recreating it from memory.

Comment: If you're using an existing map and redrawing it, it's not "from scratch", and the original map-maker's work is protected. Do you mean that you are inventing a map that you feel matches a verbal description in a book?

Comment: @user6726 I updated my question.

Comment: Answered here:. http://law.stackexchange.com/a/11093/3851

Answer (score 4):

That would be pretty much a classical case of copyright infringement. Drawing a thing from memory is copying just as much as drawing a thing with the original before you or xeroxing a thing. The degree of match between the original and your copy may vary depending on how good your memory is, but that doesn't matter, because copyright protection is not about "making exact replicas", it is about copying in any form.